# How to add new path to $PATH variable in a post-installation script of RPM?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, rpm, environment-variables

I want to automatically add a new path to the $PATH variable each time when my RPM package is installed.

I tried to use a post-installation script in the my RPM. Here is the part of RPM spec file containing this post installation script:

```
%post
PATH=$PATH:/usr/app/mdg/bin
export PATH
```

But after successful installation the $PATH doesn't changed. Please help me with that issue.

Answer (score 3):

When you're adding the path in the RPM's post-script, it is only being set for the duration of the installation shell.

Within your RPM, you want to install a `custom.sh` file under `/etc/profile.d/`.

```
# cat /etc/profile.d/custom.sh
#!/bin/bash

PATH=$PATH:/usr/app/mdg/bin
export PATH
```

If you're using CSH, the file should be named `custom.csh`.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a soft link to the bin path instead of changing an environment variable:

```
%install 
# ...
ln -s /usr/app/mdg/bin/your-program /usr/bin/your-program
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45540/how-to-automatically-add-new-path-to-path-variable-after-rpm-packet-installatio

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the application to PATH you can create a soft link to the path already existing in the PATH. However, I would suggest creating what link in `%post` step - which will be executed on the target machine instead of build agent. The reason for that is you might need `sudo` privileges to add the link in `%build` or `%install` step. If you create the link in `%post` then you you will use `sudo` either way, but on the other host.

```
%define _location /usr/app/%{_name}

...

%post
ln -sf %{_location}/bin/%{_name} /usr/bin/%{_name}
# ln -sf /usr/app/mdg/bin/mdg /usr/bin/mdg
```

Also remember to remove the link when you remove the application from the machine:

```
%postun
unlink /usr/bin/%{_name}
# unlink /usr/bin/mdg
```